# Leaflet: How to display markers behind polygons?

Tags: leaflet, markers, polygons, z-order

I need icons (PNG) and polygons on my map. So I create icons as markers and polygons as polygons. Unfortunately regardless of creation order polygons are displayed "below" markers. I need is vice-versa. Is there a way, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Correct default panes order in Leaflet 0.x: (from top-most to bottom-most)

1. objectsPane

   1. popupPane
   2. markerPane <= all markers icon (other than `L.CircleMarker`)
   3. shadowPane <= all markers **icon shadow**
   4. overlayPane <= all vectors (including `L.CircleMarker`)
2. tilePane

So just using the marker's icon shadow is not enough. You have to manually change the `z-index` of those panes in CSS (or through JS).

See also [Leaflet: Polyline above Marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808944/leaflet-polyline-above-marker/33813645#33813645).

---

Original answer:

The stack order of vectors (like your polygons) and Markers is fixed in Leaflet 0.x. They are inserted into "[panes](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-panes)" which order is (from top-most to bottom-most):

1. popupPane
2. markerPane <= all markers icon (other than `L.CircleMarker`)
3. overlayPane <= all vectors (including `L.CircleMarker`)
4. shadowPane <= all markers **icon shadow**
5. tilePane

So you should be able to easily workaround this fixed order by using the Marker's [Icon **shadow**](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icon-shadowurl). If you still want the user to be able to click on your marker, simply use a transparent image for the normal icon, with the same size as your shadow image.

The situation is different in Leaflet 1.0. You can create your own panes (`map.createPane`), set their order by specifying their `zIndex` (possibly through CSS), and specify where your vectors and markers go by using their `pane` (and `shadowPane` for markers) option(s).

Comment: Turns out the initial given order is wrong by default. You have to manually change the `z-index` of these panes in CSS. See [Leaflet: Polyline above Marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808944/leaflet-polyline-above-marker/33813645#33813645)