# Leaflet: Polyline above Marker

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am working with Leaflet 0.7.7 and have a marker type that should go behind Polylines that I draw.

Usually markers are rendered above all Paths but is there a way to get a marker to render below? Thanks.

Comment: See [Leaflet - how to display markers behind polygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542254/leaflet-how-to-display-markers-behind-polygons/33544452#33544452)

Comment: I tried using the shadowUrl option with a clear image as the icon but the marker is still above the Polyline. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Turns out that the panes order I gave in linked post is wrong… :-S you can easily work around though. Let me put a short answer with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply change the `z-index` in CSS for the `overlayPane` (where your vectors / polylines are included) and `shadowPane` (where shadows are placed), or even the `markerPane` if you want ALL markers to be placed below vectors.

```css
.leaflet-overlay-pane { z-index: 5; }
.leaflet-shadow-pane  { z-index: 4; }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/39/

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Comment: @ghybs this saved me a long research. I want to draw my polyline above the marker. So I had to change the overlay-pane to be greater than the marker pane. is there any cleaner solution?

Comment: @Nap with Leaflet 1.x, you can now create your own map panes and specify to each individual layer into which pane they should go. Then you order the panes order through `z-index` as was already the case before (and shown in the above answer).